# Is there a word for a crime against God himself?

Tags: word-request

I am curious to know if there's any such word. You have ordinary crimes, and then divine crimes like trying to stab God, spitting on God, etc. Is there a name for it? I am thinking blasphemy, but blasphemy doesn't really describe just how much more blasphemous such acts are compared to ordinary blasphemy.

Comment: For starters, who says "God" is male? And each religion seems to define for itself what a so-called "crime" against  its deity may be.

Comment: @frbsfok How would one go about stabbing God or spitting on God? I am a Christian and I believe Jesus was God in the flesh. But, at the present time, how would someone spit on or stab someone who has no body? How do you physically assault a spiritual being? By the way, you ask some tough questions sometimes. They really require some thought. 

Comment: Why did someone vote down this question as well as the both of the answers? Is it allowed to do this for no reason?

Comment: What do you mean by ***ordinary*** *blasphemy*? What do you mean by *a crime against God*?

Comment: "How would one go about stabbing God or spitting on God? " In Spanish people sometimes say _me cago en Dios_ ("I shit on God") and in the Middle Ages English people used to use expressions which supposed that God has a physical body, such as "God's teeth!" "God's arms and skin!". The whole point is that God's isn't "real" in a physical sense, and thus this type of spoken transgression is just blasphemy, no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word sacrilegious means unholy, godless, and can be used to describe an act that is a betrayal towards God. The word is synonymous with blasphemous, but as you were looking for, it holds more weight in a religious context because of the connotations attached to the word.

Answer (score -1):

Speaking from a Christian perspective, except for blasphemy, I can't give a name for the kind of thing you have in mind. However, all sins, even those committed against others are crimes against God. Since God is the ruler of the universe, my best attempt to give you a term would be the word, "rebellion." Every act of disobedience to God is rebellion.

See definition No.2 [on this page.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rebellion#English)